# How to infer keys of the second generic type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function that returns a map of all keys of the given parameter where all values are set to `true`.

```js
function useTest<
    TElement extends Element = Element,
    TObj extends {} = {}
>(object: TObj) {
    const keys = (Object.keys(object) as (keyof TObj)[]).reduce(
        (acc, current) => ({
            ...acc,
            [current]: true,
        }),
        {} as Record<keyof TObj, true>
    )

    const element = {} as TElement
    // ... do something with element

    return [keys, element] as const
}
```

When I use the function without specifying the generic type, I get the correct suggestions:

```js
const obj = {
    one: {
        a: "1"
    },
    two: {
        b: "2"
    }
}

const [keys] = useTest(obj)
//      ^
//      Record<"one" | "two", true>
```

But when I now explicitly set the first generic type, I get this:

```js
const [keys] = useTest<HTMLDivElement>(obj)
//      ^
//      Record<never, true>
```

**How can I tell the compiler to continue to infer the second generic type, instead of expecting the empty default object?**

I don't want to write:

```js
useTest<HTMLDivElement, typeof obj>(obj)
```

Comment: TypeScript currently does not have partial type inference. There is a proposal here https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242. Right now, you can only specify all generic types explicitly or none.

Comment: It won't help with your problem but eslint gives warning with your code. Don't use `{}` as a type. `{}` actually means "any non-nullish value". Record<string,unknown> or {[key:string]:unknown} is what you want I think.